# $ \int |y-x| d \mu (y) \leq \int |y-x| d \nu (y)$ then for $\phi$ convex $ \int \phi(y) d \mu (y) \leq \int \phi(y) d \nu (y)$

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis

How to prove that for two measures with finite moments,

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb R,  \quad \int |y-x| d \mu (y) \leq  \int |y-x| d \nu (y)$$
$ \qquad \qquad \implies \forall \phi, \text{ convex function, we have that }$
$$\int \phi(y) d \mu (y) \leq  \int \phi(y) d \nu (y) $$

Perhaps there should also be the condition: $$ \int d \mu = \int d \nu $$

but for this I am not sure. That is the reason why I would like to find the proof.

---

My attempt.

I tried to approximate any convex function with functions like $(y-x)^+$ but it is hard to get jumps with continuous function like this one. I was thinking of multiplying by a constant $(y-x)^+$  to get a steeper slope, and combining $(y-x_0)^+$  with $(y-x_1)^+$  in order to get a constant function over the interval $[x_0, x_1]$, but it seems to me it is not exactly the right approach.

---

Source.

It is from the book Peacocks and Associated Martingales, with Explicit Constructions, exercise 1.7. The topics related are ordering of measures, convex order of measures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple thoughts, I think I have settle down this problem. Here is my approach:

We work under the measure $\mu$.

First we prove that we can  approximate any characteristic function by a sequence of linear combination of Call function.

We prove the result for real valued functions, since transferring the problem to multi-dimensional spaces is straight-forward. We only prove the statement for sets of the form : $[a, \infty[$ and $a \in \mathbb  R$.  This proves for any set of the Borel set of $\mathbb R$ using the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.

\vspace{0.2cm}

The proof goes as follows: first we fix $a, c \in \mathbb R$ and we are searching for a sequence of function $\phi_n$, constructed with Call functions such that $\phi_n$ approximates $c \cdot 1_{ [a,\infty[}$.

We set $\forall n\in \mathbb N, \phi_n(x) = c \cdot n \left [ ( x - (a - \frac 1 n))^+ - (x - a)^+ \right ]$.

Then, the error of the approximation is given by:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^d} | c \cdot 1{ [a,\infty[} - \phi_n | d \mu &= 
\int_{a - \frac 1 n}^{a} | c - c \cdot n  [  x - a + \frac 1 n ] | d \mu \\
&= \int_{a - \frac 1 n}^{a} | c \cdot n ( x - a ) | d \mu \\
&=  \frac c {2n} .
\end{align*}

Then, $\phi_n$ converges to $1_{ [a,\infty[}$ in $L^1 (d  \mu)$. Now, since any positive measurable function can be approximated by a sequence of linear combination of simple functions, we can approximate any positive measurable function by a linear combination of Call functions.

Then, it is easy to prove the statement with dominated convergence :)